# How do I get Nvidia drivers to work with mainline PPA kernels?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, nvidia

I installed the 2.6.36 kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/ because it's the first version to supports my soundcard (this works) but now I can't get my Geforce 310M to work. I used the 256.53 Version which works with 2.6.35 but that won't install because of mismatching gcc versions with the kernel (yes i selected ignore but it won't install). the newer 260 Version installs but i only get a black screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug with how the Ubuntu Kernel Team is building the mainline kernels. They appear to be building on a Hardy (8.04) system (with gcc 4.2.3-2ubuntu7). In the meantime, you could try building the Nvidia drivers within a Hardy chroot. Tthough somewhat overkill for this case, you could [set up the chroot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/BuildEnvironment) and build it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the mainline builds with the nvidia driver (due to gcc versions, as you note).

Compile it yourself. It's not nearly as hard as it sounds. I download the latest source from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) and build it ["the old fashioned way"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate%20Build%20Method%3a%20The%20Old-Fashioned%20Debian%20Way). Takes 20 minutes once you know what you're doing and is compatible with the ubuntu-given nvidia driver (and manually installed, if you're that way too).

It's suprisingly good (albeit geeky) fun too.

Comment: This seems logic but unfortunatly it didn't work the kernel now is compiled with the correct gcc version but still the NVIDIA installation fails (unable to build ...)

Comment: You built the headers package and installed it too?

Comment: Yes i installed them too, the kernel is running but nvidia still won't build

Answer (score 1):

[Liquorix](http://liquorix.net/) ZEN-based kernel works on my Maverick desktop with NVidia 8600 and latest nvidia-current.